# OpenLayers Interaction is immediately removed after mouse click?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I have created a map according to OpenLayers 5.3.
according the docs @ here https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/draw-features.html
I draw a feature/interaction, however this 'point' is immediately removed after mouse click.
you may view my live map @
https://ramzingate.com/map.html and view the source code
try to click on the map to create a point/feature. but it is Removed !!!!!
I need to keep this point, and get the LonLat coordinates..

```
///// Creating a centering point on the map view and drawing a circle around it
var centerLongitudeLatitude = ol.proj.fromLonLat([51.338076, 35.699756]);
const source = new ol.source.Vector({
                                    wrapX: false,
//                                  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
//                                  features: [new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Circle(centerLongitudeLatitude, 550))]
                                    });

    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: source,
      style: [
        new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#f75f62',
            width: 2
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(247,95,98, 0.35)'
          })
        })
      ]
    });
    
    raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    });

    var myMap = new ol.Map({
        layers: [layer],
        target: 'map',
        key: 'web.uNSRgsxSeuCdyNCZSMvciGHZBCDatUaXbGgaHN05',
        maptype: 'dreamy-gold',
        poi: true,
        traffic: false,
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([51.338076, 35.699756]),
            zoom: 15
        })
    });


    //// Here is where I am trying to enable draw a feature with interaction
    let draw; //// global so we can remove it later
    
    function addInteraction() {

    // myMap.removeInteraction(draw);

      draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
         source: source,
         type: 'Point', // Point,Polygon,Circle
      });
        
    // draw.removeLastPoint();
      myMap.addInteraction(draw);
    }

    
    //////////////// Call the Draw Interaction
    addInteraction();
```

need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot see the drawn points because your style does not include `image` or `text` which are the only style types which support point geometry.  Adding an image to the style will fix it, for example

```
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#f75f62',
        width: 2
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(247,95,98, 0.35)'
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 6,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: '#f75f62',
        })
      })
    })
```